# Get ResponseHeaders from WebClient after OpenReadCompleted

Tags: silverlight, webclient

I would like to get the filename out of the Content-Disposition header when a WebClient OpenReadAsync is completed. I can see the header in my response in Fiddler, but when I try to access it from Silverlight I get a `System.NotImplementedException` - This property is not implemented by this class.

Is there any way to get to these headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response Headers are not supported in Browser Http Handling. You must specify Client Http Handling before calling your HttpHandler:

**bool httpResult = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);**

WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);

wc.OpenReadAsync(...);

The result headers will now be available on the webClient object in the wc_OpenReadCompleted method. Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=vs.95).aspx